# squid3 how to make a computer avoid the blocking rules

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a set of rules blocking access to swf and other types of content that can relate to streaming, video, music and online radios.
How can I allow a certain computer on a network to bypass these blocking rules so that user can access this type of content?

Example block rules:

```
acl whitelist dstdomain "/etc/squid3/sites.whitelist.txt"
http_access allow whitelist


#streaming files
http_access deny fails
http_reply_access deny fails
http_access deny fails2
http_reply_access deny fails2
http_access deny x-type
http_reply_access deny x-type
http_access deny x-type2
http_reply_access deny x-type2

http_access allow localnet

http_access deny all
```

I did try to place the specific websites in the whitelist but didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule order matters in Squid. Once a rule allows or denies an ACL then the remaining rules are ignored.

Create an ACL for the computer IP address that you don't want blocked. Put the rule that allows it before your content blocking rules.

```
acl dontblock src 10.10.1.20/32 #IP of computer that shouldn't have any content blocked
http_access allow dontblock #allows one computer to not have any content blocked
*Isert your deny rules here*
http_access allow localnet #allows everything else to other computers
```